# Cannot get sprite to collide with map images (java)

Tags: java

I am creating a 2D game which the zombie moves with WASD keys and is supposed to collide with the walls and not enter them, as well as collide with the brains and removes them. Every type of code I have used does not create collision. I am using a zombie sprite sheet i found on google as well as 2 backgroundless images for walls and brains.

After I figure out collision, I then then to implement a autorun sequence to where it bounces around like a screensaver and does the same thing just automatically until all brains are collected.

The EZ is just a library that is utilized by UH Manoa, that can be found here: [EZ Graphics](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~dylank/ics111/)

Main

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ZombieMain {

    static EZImage[] walls = new EZImage[500];
    static EZImage[] sideWalls = new EZImage[500];
    static EZImage[] brains = new EZImage[50];
    static int wallsCount = 0;
    static int sideWallsCount = 0;
    static int brainsCount = 0;

    /*public static void addWall(EZImage wall) {
        walls[wallsCount] = wall;
        wallsCount++;
    }

    public static void addCoin(EZImage brain) {
        brains[brainsCount] = brain;
        brainsCount++;
    }*/

    /*public static void CollisingCoin(EZImage me) {

        int x = me.getXCenter();
        int y = me.getYCenter();
        for (int i = 0; i < brainsCount; i++) {
            if ((brains[i].isPointInElement(me.getXCenter() - 30, me.getYCenter() - 30))
                    || (brains[i].isPointInElement(me.getXCenter() + 30, me.getYCenter() - 30))
                    || (brains[i].isPointInElement(me.getXCenter() - 30, me.getYCenter() + 30))
                    || (brains[i].isPointInElement(me.getXCenter() + 30, me.getYCenter() + 30))) {
                brains[i].translateTo(-20, -20);
                System.out.println("You ate a brain!");
            }
        }
    }*/

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

        //initialize scanner
        Scanner fScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("boundaries.txt"));

        int w = fScanner.nextInt();
        int h = fScanner.nextInt();
        String inputText = fScanner.nextLine();

        //create backdrop
        EZ.initialize(w*33,h*32);
        EZ.setBackgroundColor(new Color(0, 0,0));
        Zombie me = new Zombie("zombieSheet.png", 650, 450, 65, 63, 10);


        //set reading parameters and establish results of case readings
        int row = 0;

        while(fScanner.hasNext()) {

            inputText = fScanner.nextLine();

            for (int column = 0; column < inputText.length(); column++){

                char ch = inputText.charAt(column);

                switch(ch){
                case 'W':
                    walls[wallsCount] = EZ.addImage("barbwire.jpg", column*32, row*32);
                    wallsCount++;
                    break;      
                case 'M':
                    sideWalls[wallsCount] = EZ.addImage("barb.jpg", column*32, row*32);
                    wallsCount++;
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    brains[brainsCount] = EZ.addImage("brains.png", column*32, row*32);
                    brainsCount++;
                    break;
                default:
                    // Do nothing
                    break;

                }

                //printed count of walls, side walls, and brains
                System.out.println("W = " + wallsCount);
                System.out.println("M = " + sideWallsCount);
                System.out.println("B = " + brainsCount);

            }
            row++;
        }

        fScanner.close();

        while (true) {

            // check if going to collide with wall
            // we want to check this before we actually move
            // otherwise, we get "stuck" in a situation where we can't move
            // if no collision, we can move

            /*if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('a')) {
                if (!isCollisingWall(me, -2, 0)) {
                    me.translateBy(-2, 0);
                }
            } else if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('d')) {
                if (!isCollisingWall(me, 2, 0)) {
                    me.translateBy(2, 0);
                }
            } else if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('w')) {
                if (!isCollisingWall(me, 0, -2)) {
                    me.translateBy(0, -2);
                }
            } else if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('s')) {
                if (!isCollisingWall(me, 0, 2)) {
                    me.translateBy(0, 2);
                }
            }*/
            me.go();
            EZ.refreshScreen();
        }

    }

}
```

Sprite

```
public class Zombie {

    EZImage zombieSheet;

    int x = 0;              // Position of Sprite
    int y = 0;
    int zombieWidth;        // Width of each sprite
    int zombieHeight;       // Height of each sprite
    int direction = 0;      // Direction character is walking in
    int walkSequence = 0;   // Walk sequence counter
    int cycleSteps;         // Number of steps before cycling to next animation step
    int counter = 0;        // Cycle counter


    Zombie(String imgFile, int startX, int startY, int width, int height, int steps) {
        x = startX;                 // position of the sprite character on the screen
        y = startY;
        zombieWidth = width;        // Width of the sprite character
        zombieHeight = height;      // Height of the sprite character
        cycleSteps = steps;         // How many pixel movement steps to move before changing the sprite graphic
        zombieSheet = EZ.addImage(imgFile, x, y);
        setImagePosition();
    }

    private void setImagePosition() {

        // Move the entire sprite sheet
        zombieSheet.translateTo(x, y);

        // Show only a portion of the sprite sheet.
        // Portion is determined by setFocus which takes 4 parameters:
        // The 1st two numbers is the top left hand corner of the focus region.
        // The 2nd two numbers is the bottom right hand corner of the focus region.
        zombieSheet.setFocus(walkSequence * zombieWidth, direction, walkSequence * zombieWidth + zombieWidth, direction + zombieHeight);
    }

    public void moveDown(int stepSize) {
        y = y + stepSize;

        direction = 0;

        if ((counter % cycleSteps) == 0) {
            walkSequence++;
            if (walkSequence > 6)
                walkSequence = 0;
        }
        counter++;
        setImagePosition();
    }

    public void moveLeft(int stepSize) {
        x = x - stepSize;
        direction = zombieHeight * 2;

        if ((counter % cycleSteps) == 0) {
            walkSequence--;
            if (walkSequence < 0)
                walkSequence = 6;
        }
        counter++;
        setImagePosition();
    }

    public void moveRight(int stepSize) {
        x = x + stepSize;
        direction = zombieHeight;

        if ((counter % cycleSteps) == 0) {
            walkSequence++;
            if (walkSequence > 6)
                walkSequence = 0;
        }
        counter++;

        setImagePosition();
    }

    public void moveUp(int stepSize) {
        y = y - stepSize;
        direction = zombieHeight * 3;

        if ((counter % cycleSteps) == 0) {
            walkSequence--;
            if (walkSequence < 0)
                walkSequence = 6;
        }
        setImagePosition();

        counter++;
    }


    // Keyboard controls for moving the character.
    public void go() {
        if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('w')) {
            moveUp(2);
        } else if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('a')) {
            moveLeft(2);
        } else if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('s')) {
            moveDown(2);
        } else if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('d')) {
            moveRight(2);
        }
    }

    public void translateBy(int i, int j) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public int getXCenter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return x;
    }

    public int getYCenter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }



}
```

Comment: What's this "EZ" library you seem to be using? Without more information, it's going to be impossible to provide you with an answer as it's not part of the standard API

Comment: its linked inside my paragraph at the top

Answer (score 1):

`EZElement` provides a `getBounds` property, which returns a `java.awt.Shape` object; why is this important? Because the Java 2D Graphics API already provides some hit detection.

From this, we then need to determine the player shape's intersection with any other shapes. To do this, we need to wrap both shapes in a `Area` and use it to make the final determinations.

```
Area meArea = new Area(me.getBounds());
Area checkArea = new Area(elementToCheck.getBounds());
checkArea(meArea);
if (!checkArea.isEmpty()) {
    //... We have collision
}
```

Obviously, this should all be wrapped up in some kind of method to handle the core functionality, but you could have a helper method which simply took two `EZElement`s and return `true`/`false` if the collide

For brevity and testing, I stripped back your example, but the basic idea should continue to work

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    private List<EZImage> brains = new ArrayList<>(25);

    private Zombie me;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {

        int w = 10;
        int h = 10;

        //create backdrop
        EZ.initialize(w * 33, h * 32);
        EZ.setBackgroundColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        me = new Zombie("Zombie.png", 0, 0);

        brains.add(EZ.addImage("Brains.png", (w * 33) / 2, (h * 32 / 2)));

        while (true) {
            detectCollision();
            // check if going to collide with wall
            // we want to check this before we actually move
            // otherwise, we get "stuck" in a situation where we can't move
            // if no collision, we can move
            /*if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('a')) {
                        if (!isCollisingWall(me, -2, 0)) {
                            me.translateBy(-2, 0);
                        }
                    } else if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('d')) {
                        if (!isCollisingWall(me, 2, 0)) {
                            me.translateBy(2, 0);
                        }
                    } else if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('w')) {
                        if (!isCollisingWall(me, 0, -2)) {
                            me.translateBy(0, -2);
                        }
                    } else if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('s')) {
                        if (!isCollisingWall(me, 0, 2)) {
                            me.translateBy(0, 2);
                        }
                    }*/
            me.go();
            EZ.refreshScreen();
        }
    }

    public boolean doesCollide(EZElement element, EZElement with) {
        Area a = new Area(element.getBounds());
        Area b = new Area(with.getBounds());
        a.intersect(b);
        return !a.isEmpty();
    }

    public void detectCollision() {
        Iterator<EZImage> obstacles = brains.iterator();
        while (obstacles.hasNext()) {
            EZElement next = obstacles.next();
            if (doesCollide(me.zombieSheet, next)) {
                System.out.println("Me = " + me.getBounds().getBounds());
                System.out.println("next = " + next.getBounds().getBounds());
                EZ.removeEZElement(next);
                obstacles.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Zombie {

        EZImage zombieSheet;

        int x = 0;              // Position of Sprite
        int y = 0;

        Zombie(String imgFile, int startX, int startY) {
            x = startX;                 // position of the sprite character on the screen
            y = startY;
            zombieSheet = EZ.addImage(imgFile, x, y);
            setImagePosition();
        }

        public Shape getBounds() {
            return zombieSheet.getBounds();
        }

        private void setImagePosition() {

            // Move the entire sprite sheet
            zombieSheet.translateTo(x, y);
        }

        public void moveDown(int stepSize) {
            y = y + stepSize;
            setImagePosition();
        }

        public void moveLeft(int stepSize) {
            x = x - stepSize;
            setImagePosition();
        }

        public void moveRight(int stepSize) {
            x = x + stepSize;
            setImagePosition();
        }

        public void moveUp(int stepSize) {
            y = y - stepSize;
            setImagePosition();
        }

        // Keyboard controls for moving the character.
        public void go() {
            if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('w')) {
                moveUp(2);
            } else if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('a')) {
                moveLeft(2);
            } else if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('s')) {
                moveDown(2);
            } else if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('d')) {
                moveRight(2);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you give each entity (and block/tile) a collision box, then test if a specific entity's bounding box collided with another entity's bounding box, then make it so that the entities can't move in that direction until there isn't a bounding box in a direction, if that made any since.
Do the same for testing for the brains, though I recommend making an ArrayList of brains, and removing specific ones if that brain had been touched.